# Login Not working on Mobile Browser

Tags: php

I create a login script it working properly on pc browser,But when use same code for mobile browser it can't redirect me on home page.So i can't understand where is the problem.Any one can help me?
Code on login.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
@session_start();
include 'conn.php';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
        Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

        <title>Admin Login</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="Bheem">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/admin_style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <header>

            </header>
            <nav>

            </nav>

            <div>
<div id="login-content-wrp">
        <h2 class="login-tit" >Admin Login</h2>

        <form name="login" onsubmit="return val()" method="post">
        <div id="login-content" >
          <div class="con-row" >

            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="txt-box" placeholder="User Name"  name="txtuname"/>
            <span class="error" id="blank-user" >Please Enter User Name</span>

          </div>
          <div class="con-row" >

            <input type="password" autocomplete="off" class="txt-box" placeholder="Password" name="txtpass" />
            <span class="error" id="blank-password" >Please Enter Password</span>
          </div>
          <div class="con-row" >

            <input type="submit" class="btn-login"  name="btnlogin" value="Login" />
            <span class="error" id="invaild-user-pass" >Please Enter Valid User Name OR Password!</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
            </div>

            <footer>

            </footer>
        </div>

<script>
    function val()
     {
        if(document.login.txtuname.value=='')
        {
            document.getElementById("blank-user").style.display = "block";

            document.login.txtuname.focus();
            return false;
        } 
        else{
            document.getElementById("blank-user").style.display = "none";
        }
        if(document.login.txtpass.value=='')
        {
            document.getElementById("blank-password").style.display = "block";
            document.login.txtpass.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("blank-password").style.display = "none";
        }
        return true;
     }
</script>
 <?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin_id']))
{
if(isset($_POST['btnlogin']))
{
    $uname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtuname']);
    $pass=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtpass']);
    $query = "select * from tbl_admin where user_name='$uname' and password=md5('$pass')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $row['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['admin_name'] = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION['admin_img'] = $row['image'];
        $_SESSION['admin_pass'] = $row['password'];
        setcookie('adminname',$row['user_name'],time()+(60 * 60 * 24 * 30), "/");
        setcookie('password',$row['password'],time()+(60 * 60 * 24 * 30), "/");
        header("location:home.php");
        exit ;
    }
    else {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("invaild-user-pass").style.display = "block";
</script>
<?php   
}
}
}
?>
<?php   
//ob_end_flush();
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Code on Home.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<?php 
include '../conn.php';
    ob_start();
@session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin_id'])){
die("<script>location.href = 'login.php'</script>");
}
 ?>
    <head>
        <?php include 'header_viewport.php'; ?>

        <title>Admin Section</title>

        <?php
         include 'header_links.php';
        ?>
    </head>

    <body class="nav-md">

        <div class="container body">

            <div class="main_container">

                <div class="col-md-3 left_col">
                    <div class="left_col scroll-view">

                        <?php
                        include "sidebar_menu.php";

                        include "navigation.php";
                        ?>

                        <!-- page content -->
                        <div class="right_col" role="main">

                            <!-- top tiles -->
                            <!-- <div class="row tile_count">
                            <div class="animated flipInY col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 tile_stats_count">
                            <div class="left"></div>
                            <div class="right">
                            <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Total Users</span>
                            <div class="count">2500</div>
                            <span class="count_bottom"><i class="green">4% </i> From last Week</span>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="animated flipInY col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 tile_stats_count">
                            <div class="left"></div>
                            <div class="right">
                            <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Average Time</span>
                            <div class="count">123.50</div>
                            <span class="count_bottom"><i class="green"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>3% </i> From last Week</span>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="animated flipInY col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 tile_stats_count">
                            <div class="left"></div>
                            <div class="right">
                            <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Total Males</span>
                            <div class="count green">2,500</div>
                            <span class="count_bottom"><i class="green"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>34% </i> From last Week</span>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="animated flipInY col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 tile_stats_count">
                            <div class="left"></div>
                            <div class="right">
                            <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Total Females</span>
                            <div class="count">4,567</div>
                            <span class="count_bottom"><i class="red"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>12% </i> From last Week</span>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="animated flipInY col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 tile_stats_count">
                            <div class="left"></div>
                            <div class="right">
                            <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Total Collections</span>
                            <div class="count">2,315</div>
                            <span class="count_bottom"><i class="green"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>34% </i> From last Week</span>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="animated flipInY col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 tile_stats_count">
                            <div class="left"></div>
                            <div class="right">
                            <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Total Connections</span>
                            <div class="count">7,325</div>
                            <span class="count_bottom"><i class="green"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>34% </i> From last Week</span>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            </div> -->
                            <!-- /top tiles -->

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="dashboard_graph">

                                        <div class="row x_title">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <h3>Customers <small>Details</small></h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <table class="table">

                                                <thead>

                                                    <tr>

                                                        <th>#</th>

                                                        <th>Name</th>

                                                        <th>Phone No.</th>

                                                        <th>Email</th>
                                                        <th>Product</th>
                                                        <th>Start Date</th>
                                                        <th>End Date</th>
                                                        <th>Status</th>


                                                    </tr>

                                                </thead>

                                                <tbody>
                                                    <?php
                                                    $count = 1;
                                                    $query = "select  c.*,cp.product_pk,cp.start_date,cp.end_date,p.name as product_name from tbl_customer c left join customer_products cp on c.pk=cp.customer_pk left join tbl_product p on p.pk=cp.product_pk limit 5";
                                                    $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
                                                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                                    {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $row['mobile'] ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $row['product_name'] ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $row['start_date'] ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $row['end_date'] ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php if($row['status']==1){
                                                            ?>
                                                            <input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
                                                            <?php

                                                        }
else{
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox"  />
    <?php
} 
                                                         ?></td>

                                                    </tr>
                                                    <?php
                                                    $count = $count + 1;
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>

                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 bg-white">

                                        </div>

                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        <a href="customers.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right" >View All</a>
                                        <br>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <br />

                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="user_sug" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="x_panel">
                                        <div class="x_title">
                                            <h2>User Suggestions</h2>
                                            <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                                                </li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="x_content">
                                            <div class="dashboard-widget-content">

                                                <ul class="list-unstyled timeline widget">
                                                    <?php
                                                    $query = "select * from tbl_suggestion order by date desc limit 5";
                                                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                                                     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                                     {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="block">
                                                            <div class="block_content">
                                                                <h2 class="title"><a><?php echo $row['email'] ?></a></h2>
                                                                <div class="byline">
                                                                    <span><?php echo date('d M Y',strtotime($row['date'])); ?></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <p class="excerpt">
                                                                    <?php echo $row['suggestion']; ?>
                                                                </p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <?php
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                        <br>           
                                        <a href="suggestions.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right" >View All</a>


                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                                    <div class="row">

                                        <div id="user_enq" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <div class="x_panel">
                                                <div class="x_title">
                                                    <h2>User Enquiry </h2>
                                                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <!-- <li class="dropdown">
                                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                        <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                        </li> -->
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="x_content">
                                                    <div class="dashboard-widget-content">
                                                        <table class="table" >
                                                            <thead>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <th>#</th>
                                                                    <th>Date</th>
                                                                    <th>Name</th>
                                                                    <th>Address</th>
                                                                    <th>Email</th>
                                                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                                                    <th>Institute Name</th>
                                                                    <th>Institute Head</th>
                                                                    <th>Product Name</th>
                                                                    <th>Message</th>
                                                                </tr>

                                                            </thead>
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <?php
                                                                $count = 1;
                                                                $query = "select * from tbl_enquiry order by date desc limit 5";
                                                                $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
                                                                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                                                {
                                                                ?>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td><?php echo $count ?></td>
                                                                    <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
                                                                    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                                                                    <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
                                                                    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                                                                    <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
                                                                    <td><?php echo $row['institute_name']; ?></td>
                                                                    <td><?php echo $row['institute_head']; ?></td>
                                                                    <td><?php echo $row['product']; ?></td>
                                                                    <td><?php echo $row['message']; ?></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <?php
                                                                $count += 1;
                                                                }
                                                                ?>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>         
                                        <a href="enquiries.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right" >View All</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <?php
                            include "footer.php";
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /page content -->

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div id="custom_notifications" class="custom-notifications dsp_none">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled notifications clearfix" data-tabbed_notifications="notif-group"></ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div id="notif-group" class="tabbed_notifications"></div>
                </div>

            <?php
            include 'footer_links.php';
            ?>  
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set HTTP response code to 302. Setting `Location` header is generally not enough.

Also, don't store password in cookie, don't store username in cookie, cookie should be a session identifier, which you use on server to look up which user has current session. **Storing password in cookie is insecure.**

Comment: Please provide me solution in detail.how i can set HTTP response code to 302?